# ASP.NET DbSet identity property over another DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext, dbset

In my ASP.NET CORE API project I have two different DB contexts for two different databases.

One context for the identity (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity) and the second for the data.

The problem is that data content relates to the identity, and in code I need to know this values.

I have a class named "Topic", every topic relates to a identity. The class looks like:

```
public class Topic
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ApiUserId { get; set; }

[Required]
    public virtual ApiUser ApiUser { get; set; } 
// the ApiUser class is based on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But when I now add an migration for the data context, it includes the creation of the ApiUser table.

This ApiUser table is already in the identity context and should be integrated from there.

Is there a way to configure a DbContext's DbSet like this?

My data context looks like this:

```
public class dataContext : DbContext
{
    public dataContext(DbContextOptions<dataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe other relevant services I've configured:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApiUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<identityContext>();
```

Is it possible to map the Topic class property ApiUser to the identity context?

Like the DbSet identity property should handle over another DbContext access.

I hope I wrote my issue understandable, otherwise let me know.

In my thoughts there is a way to define the load action for this identity property.

Thanks already for solutions or tips how you would solve this.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use two contexts or could you move the identity tables into the same database as the other context?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have two DbContext with two databases. If you want to have APIUser and Topics in one context, you should create one DbContext. Still, you have other options. For example, you can create a table inside dataContext for the ApiUser table, but this table holds related information(like ID, FullName,...) about ApiUser for the Topic table(Or solution).In this approach, you should update the ApiUser table inside datacontext after every change in the second dbContext.